# Prime factorization algorithm fails for big numbers

Tags: java

I have run into a weird issue for problem 3 of Project Euler. The program works for other numbers that are small, like 13195, but it throws this error when I try to crunch a big number like 600851475143:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at euler3.Euler3.main(Euler3.java:16)
```

Here's my code:

```
    //Number whose prime factors will be determined
    long num = 600851475143L;

    //Declaration of variables
    ArrayList factorsList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList primeFactorsList = new ArrayList();

    //Generates a list of factors
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            factorsList.add(i);
        }           
    }

    //If the integer(s) in the factorsList are divisable by any number between 1 
    //and the integer itself (non-inclusive), it gets replaced by a zero 
    for (int i = 0; i < factorsList.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < (Integer) factorsList.get(i); j++)
        {
            if ((Integer) factorsList.get(i) % j == 0)
            {
                factorsList.set(i, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    //Transfers all non-zero numbers into a new list called primeFactorsList
    for (int i = 0; i < factorsList.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((Integer) factorsList.get(i) != 0)
        {
            primeFactorsList.add(factorsList.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Why is it only big numbers that cause this error?

Comment: You could use `ArrayList<int>` instead so you don't need to typecast.

Comment: @Spoike: Not `ArrayList<int>` but `ArrayList<Integer>` - you can't use primitive types as generic type arguments in Java.

Comment: Then again, he should be using `ArrayList<Long>` instead.

Comment: he shoudln't use _any_ sort of list or array - it's trivial to compute this problem without pre-storing _any_ primes or storing the factors in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is just using `Integer`, which is a 32-bit type with a maximum value of 2147483647. It's unsurprising that it's failing when used for numbers much bigger than that. Note that your initial loop uses `int` as the loop variable, so would actually loop forever if it didn't throw an exception. The value of `i` will go from the 2147483647 to -2147483648 and continue.

Use `BigInteger` to handle arbitrarily large values, or `Long` if you're happy with a limited range but a larger one. (The maximum value of `long` / `Long` is 9223372036854775807L.)

However, I doubt that this is really the approach that's expected... it's going to take a *long* time for big numbers like that.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `BigInteger` problem mentioned by Jon Skeet, note the following:

1. you only need to test factors up to `sqrt(num)`
2. each time you find a factor, divide `num` by that factor, and then test that factor again
3. there's *really* no need to use a collection to store the primes in advance

My solution (which was originally written in Perl) would look something like this in Java:

```
long n = 600851475143L;          // the original input
long s = (long)Math.sqrt(n);     // no need to test numbers larger than this
long f = 2;                      // the smallest factor to test
do {
    if (n % f == 0) {            // check we have a factor
         n /= f;                 // this is our new number to test
         s = (long)Math.sqrt(n); // and our range is smaller again
    } else {                     // find next possible divisor
         f = (f == 2) ? 3 : f + 2;
    }
} while (f < s);                 // required result is in "n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the case as I don't know which line is which - but I notice your first loop uses an int.

```
//Generates a list of factors
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
        factorsList.add(i);
    }           
}
```

As num is a long, its possible that `num > Integer.MAX_INT` and your loop is wrapping around to negative at `MAX_INT` then looping until 0, giving you a `num % 0` operation.

Comment: Solution would be to replace all `int` with `long` then.

Answer (score 1):

## Why does your solution not work?

Well numbers are discrete in hardware. Discrete means thy have a min and max values. Java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), to store negative values, so `2147483647+1 == -2147483648`. This is because for type `int`, max value is `2147483647`. And doing this is called overflow.

It seems as if you have an `overflow bug`. Iterable value `i` first becomes negative, and eventually 0, thus you get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`. If your computer can loop 10 million statements a second, this would take **1h 10min** to reproduce, so I leave it as assumption an not a proof.

This is also reason trivially simple statements like `a+b` can produce bugs.

## How to fix it?

```
package margusmartseppcode.From_1_to_9;

public class Problem_3 {
    static long lpf(long nr) {
        long max = 0;

        for (long i = 2; i <= nr / i; i++)
            while (nr % i == 0) {
                max = i;
                nr = nr / i;
            }

        return nr > 1 ? nr : max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lpf(600851475143L));
    }
}
```

You might think: "So how does this work?"

Well my tough process went like:

1. (Dynamical programming approach) If i had list of primes **x** `{2,3,5,7,11,13,17, ...}` up to value **x<sub>i</sub> > nr / 2**, then finding largest prime factor is trivial:

   - I start from the largest prime, and start testing if devision reminder with my number is zero, if it is, then that is the answer.
   - If after looping all the elements, I did not find my answer, my number must be a prime itself.
2. (Brute force, with filters) I assumed, that

   - my numbers largest prime factor is small (under 10 million).
   - if my numbers is a multiple of some number, then I can reduce loop size by that multiple.

I used the second approach here.

Note however, that if my number would be just little off and one of `{600851475013,  600851475053,  600851475067,  600851475149,  600851475151}`, then my approach assumptions would fail and program would take ridiculously long time to run. If computer could execute 10m statements per second it would take **6.954 days**, to find the right answer.

In your **brute force** approach, just generating a list of factors would take longer - assuming you do not run out of memory before.

## Is there a better way?

Sure, in Mathematica you could write it as:

```
P3[x_] := FactorInteger[x][[-1, 1]]
P3[600851475143]
```

or just [`FactorInteger[600851475143]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FactorInteger%5B600851475143%5D), and lookup the largest value.

This works because in Mathematica you have arbitrary size integers. Java also has arbitrary size integer class called `BigInteger`.

Comment: thats **not** what discrete means.  Discrete means a variable that can only contain specific values, not _every possible value_ - it's like comparing the set of integers to the set of reals.